# Runtime Error '-2147024894 (80070002)' Can´t find the given file

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that the Sytem can't find the given file. I've checked my path and the name of the Powerpoint file, both are correct. Maybe you can help me. Thanks. This is my Code.

```
Sub Excel_to_Powerpoint()
    Dim pptPres As Presentation
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptVorlage As String
    Dim strPfad As String
    Dim strPotx As String

    strPfad = "D:\Users\BKU\CedricWirth\Desktop\DHBW_Mosbach\T2000\Test"
    strPotx = "Vorlage_PSB.potx"

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    pptVorlage = strPfad & strPotx

    pptApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=pptVorlage, untitled:=msoTrue ***here is the Error***

    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation

    pptPres.Slides(1).Select


    pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Projektschritte").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("B44").Value
    pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Behinderungen").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("B45").Value


    pptPres.SaveAs "Projektsteckbrief_" & Range("A4") & ".pptx"
    pptPres.Close
    pptApp.Quit
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214566/discussion-on-question-by-cedric-wirth-runtime-error-2147024894-80070002-ca).

Answer (score 0):

If not the path is your problem, please try the next approach:

```
Set pptPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
pptPres.ApplyTemplate (pptVorlage)
```

The meaning of the above code was to check if the path is a problem, or the way of trying to open a template.

Try, also, the next code, please:

```
Dim Shex As Object
Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shex.Open (pptVorlage)
```

Of course, you must define `pptVorlage` as we talked in comments...

Comment: VBA opens now PowerPoint, but not my "Vorlage_PSB.potx". It opens a new file

Comment: This was the idea... To open a new presentation and apply the template. Doesn't the code apply the template to the new presentation? Do you receive an error at line `pptPres.ApplyTemplate (pptVorlage)`?

Comment: Is it a similar error? I only wanted to check if the path is the problem, or your way of opening a powerpoint template... If a similar error, it looks that the path is still problematic.  Let as try the next way, to use the default application if the path is ok. I do not have space here. I will adapt the code above...

Comment: my new error is runtime error -2147188160 (80048240): Presentation (unknown member): invalid request. PowerPoint couldn't open the file.

Comment: So, it is obvious now that the path is problematic. Do you have some special character in the path which cannot be displayed here? Are you able to manually open that specific file? If yes, try write inside PowerPoint VBE `Debug.Print ActivePresentation.FullName `. What does it return?

Comment: i can open the specific file, but I don't have any Modul in PowerPoint VBE. Do I have to create a new one?

Comment: Yes. Right click on the VBAProject and insert a module. Then a simple `Sub Test` and inside it the code: `ActivePresentation.FullName`. Press Ctrl + G, to open Imediate Window and run the code. Then copy the returned path and try it in your initial code...

Comment: When I make what you said, i have a compile error. i made a forbidden use of a property. So I can't copy the path

Comment: When you write in the new Sub `Application`, does the intellisense show you the options to be used like properties/methods for the object? If yes, choose `ActivePresentation` and then see if `FullName` appears  between `ActivePresentation` properties. I think it should be there. If not, it is very strange. If yes, select it and try running the code again... If it still returns an error, this may mean that such a file does not allow macros. So, open a blank presentation, insert a module in its VBAProject, activate your template and run the code in these circumstances...

Comment: Try, also, `ActivePresentation.Path` and `ActivePresentation.TemplateName`...

Comment: I have the same error in a blank presentation too… My code is: 
Sub Test() 
Application.ActivePresentation.FullName
End Sub

Comment: Did you also try the other two above recommended options? If yes, try open an existing presentation, or save the blank one somewhere and see if it returns its full name. I tested in my computer and it does... If it returns only for the presentations, it looks that the template cannot be interrogated in this way and we must deg deeper...

Comment: Try a simple MsgBox. Does it woek?

Comment: Try something else involving Application object. If nothing works, it should be corrupred and you need to repare Office. Now I am driving and I cannot suggest something specific...

Comment: @Cedric Wirth: Did you make more tries on the Application object?

Comment: @Cedric Wirth: I am afraid, you must do it. Do you know how to do that? If not, usually, you must find your installation in Control Panel - Programs and Features, select that specific row and pres 'Change' from above header (It contains Organize, Uninstall, Change). In the next screen it must be a 'Repair' option. Then it would be good, I think, to also check for update... I wish you luck!

Comment: Do you have an idea if I can do this otherwise with an other code? Maybe this will work. I just want that cells of Excel were copied in a PowerPoint Presentation

Comment: Maybe you have an other idea to @Siddharth Rout

Comment: If your Outlook application returns an error when you try `ActivePresentation`, I do not have any idea...